# Lotus Domino Internet site document

Tags: xpages, lotus

Am developing my first Xpage application and have designed a login screen in domcfg.nsf. So when user types my url like Myrequest.com(dummy url) this should redirect me to the login page and then on succesful login attempt the page should be redirected to Myrequest pplication. Could you please let me know  how to configure in  server document or Internet site document. ?

As a first step,I executed the below points.

1. Enabled Load Internet configurations from server/Internet sites
   documents in the basic tab of server document.
2. Created new web site document by clicking on web>>Internet sites  Web
   Site-Basic Tab::

   a. **Descriptive name for this site** :myRequest.com; 
   b. **Organization**: testCompany;
   c. **Use this web site to handle requests which cannot be mapped to any other 
   web sites**: NO ;
   d. **Host names or addresses mapped to this site**: my local ip address;
   e. **Domino server that host this site** : *
3. In Web Site-Configuration Tab::
   a. **Home URL** : /myApp/myRequest.nsf?open

The rest of the configuration are all default's

When I tried opening myRequest.com no page is displayed. I guess i have made a mistake. Do i have to change any configurations ?

Comment: This question should be asked on serverfault.com instead

Comment: Sorry i did'nt find this site.is it possible to re tag or post this question in serverfault.com

Comment: not really, per, if you're a developer doing dev on a local server.

Answer (score 5):

The way this works is:

1. Set up an internet site (remember to check that your Domino server is using internet sites (first tab in the server document)
2. The internet site should not contain any information about login - just the right path etc. for the domain/subdomain to point at the right page in the right database (and possibly url redirections, headers, etc.)
3. Now create the login form, e.g. in your application database (or any other applicable database). Make sure that you have the right fields on it for the login to work - and any error messages to be correctly shown. The easiest way is to look at the standard login form (its called "$$LoginUserForm") found in domcfg.nsf (if domcfg.nsf does not exist, just create it with that name based on advanced template "Domino Web Server Configuration (8)" (template file: domcfg5.ntf)
4. Now create a Sign In Form Mapping document in domcfg.nsf. Select the specific domain/subdomain that it applies to (or a default for all websites not using another specific sign-in form), specify the path to the database with the form (e.g. your application database), and specify the name of your login form in that database
5. Now you just need to turn on the mechanism that will require your users to log in. This is done in the ACL of your database. When a user is not logged in it will obey the rules of a person entry with the name "Anonymous". If this "person" is not present in the ACL it will of course obey the default settings. You will have to determine when you want your user to log in. If you specify "No Access" then you may have to set "public read" on some of your design elements for the login form to display properly (e.g. graphic files etc.) and then you should also allow the Anonymous person to read public files (in the ACL). You may also want users to be able to read content and only be forced to log in when they want to write/change something, in which case your Anonymous user would be reader and default (or a specific group, etc.) would be author/editor - but that is all about standard Domino security/ACL and not related to web/XPages ;-)

/John

Comment: I have replied in the question section. could you help me to sort out

Comment: In the "hostname or address mapped to this site" you need to put the DNS name or IP addresss that you write in your browser (check the help by pressing the mouse down on the label and read the "pop up")