# 'Admin' user getting redirected to $$LoginUserForm

Tags: xpages

I have a user, Admin Mustermann/magerman, who is defined as an Editor Person in the ACL of my application and who has the role [Admin].

[image]

After logging in I can see that that user has the role [Admin].

but whenever I try to access my admin.xsp page, I am getting redirected to the $$LoginUserForm of my database.

The admin.xsp Page is controlled by the following ACL Access:

```
<xp:this.acl>
    <xp:acl>
        <xp:this.entries>
            <xp:aclEntry
                type="DEFAULT"
                right="NOACCESS">
            </xp:aclEntry>
            <xp:aclEntry
                type="ROLE"
                right="EDITOR"
                name="[Admin]"
                fullName="Admin">
            </xp:aclEntry>
        </xp:this.entries>
    </xp:acl>
</xp:this.acl>
```

I've also tried with the following syntax:

```
            <xp:aclEntry
                type="ROLE"
                right="EDITOR">
                <xp:this.name><![CDATA[[Admin]]]></xp:this.name>
                <xp:this.fullName><![CDATA[[Admin]]]></xp:this.fullName>
            </xp:aclEntry>
```

but to no avail.

**Update:**
I'm no longer sure it has something to do with the ACL entries on the XPage itself. Once I removed them, I land to the page but the XPages Debug Toolbar shows that I am now 'Anonymous'.

I should also mention that I'm using two directories for authentication (with directory assistance).

I don't know if this is related, but the XPages Debug Toolbar is sometimes also unresponsive (i.e. I click on the headers but nothing happens).

Is there a way of letting me track the whole authentication procedure that my server is doing? The server log is not very talky.

Comment: Can you access the xpage if you remove all the acl entries?

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes I can. But I've noticed now that after I log in, my Xpage Debug Toolbar shows me as 'Anonymous'. Also, sometimes the XPages Debug Toolbar becomes unresponsive, i.e. if I click on it nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh.

My 'Internet Website'/ domcfg.nsf setup was not correctly set up.

It's all well explained by John Daalsgard in this question:
[Lotus Domino Internet site document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742465/lotus-domino-internet-site-document).

Ironically, I have commented this as well, so I can't even pretend that I didn't know it.

Comment: It's like searching in Google and ending up with an own blog post :-D

Comment: Lol, yes that's happened to me too! I've also had a task to do, made all the design and planning on paper, gone into the database, and seen that everything had already been done, exactly has I have just planned. And then I notice that I've done the work.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you set ACL options to your XPage at all. I never used it and when I did (when I started with XPages) I always faced problems as those entries disturbed the general ACL settings when they should refine them. Never used them later.
If you want to restrict access to a special page you can workaround it with doing some scripting in the beforePageLoad event. Check roles and access and - if needed - redirect to another page.

Comment: Hi Oliver! I haven't had any kind of bad experiences with the XPages acl tag. It's atrociously named, though. I was assuming it would behave just like the acls in Client databses. It's the equivalent of the 'Security' Tab you can set up in the forms, i.e. a definition of who can read stuff with this Xpages. Once I got that, I didn't have any problems. But the overlapping meanings with the same words are really confusing.